# Unusual problem setting newline character in spark textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have Spark text area which contains the following text:
"text1\ntext2\ntext3"

Text above is showing as 3 words each on separate line.

> text1
>
> text2
>
> text3

Ok

Now i want to stylize text and add background color:

```
var tmp:String = textArea.text.replace("\n", '</span><br/><span backgroundColor="#B22300">');
textArea.textFlow = spark.utils.TextFlowUtil.importFromString('<span backgroundColor="#B22300">'+tmp+'</span>');
```

result: it's not working. Text is displayed with background color but in 2 lines:

> text1
>
> text2 text3

So my question is: what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why not just put them in separate ParagraphElements instead of spans with breaks?

Comment: RIAstar, it's a rhetorical question but i'll try your solution and see whether it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example, you write:

> text1\ntext2\text3

i'll assume you meant to write this:

> text1\ntext2\ntext3

in which case i believe it's only replacing the last instance of the new line character.  try using a regular expression with a global flag:

```
var tmp:String = textArea.text.replace(new RegExp("\\n", "g"), "</span><br/><span backgroundColor = \"#B22300\">");
```

Comment: Thanks TheDarkIn1978, i'll have to read functions definitions more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, what happens when you change `<br/>` to `<br />`? That would technically be more correct and I'll wager Flash will appreciate the closing.